# Is there a way to remove some particular words in all the rows by Python?

Tags: python

Is there a way to remove some particular words in all the rows of a dataset?

For example, there is one column contains 300 rows, and each rows contains unnecessary words,
such as :

```
$ABCD: real content 1
$ABCD: real content 2
$ABCD: real content 3
.....
```

How to remove all the $ABCD in each row?

Don't want to manually delete them because that's too many

I tried this code, but it only works for one row. when : s= df['Text'][0]

```
 s = df['Text'][0]
 print(s.replace('#ABCD:', ''))
```

it doesn't work for s= df['Text']

Comment: What have you tried? there's plenty of information on the web that could help you. Please search before you post a question

Comment: I couldn't find anything useful by myself, any suggestion for keywords?

Comment: share the code to how your data is organized

Comment: Have you tried a text editor's global change function?

Comment: `yourstring.lstrip("$ABCD:")`

Comment: Have a look into regex.  You’ll thank yourself!

Comment: If you're using Pandas, use the string utilities built-in, e.g. `df['my_column_name'].str.lstrip("$ABCD:")` to `apply` the operation along all rows. Should be faster than iteration.

Comment: @S3DEV Right on! And the docs have an extra "how to" section just for the `re` module https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html.

Comment: @Andreas Careful! That is *not* how `lstrip` works!

Comment: @KonradRudolph could you please elaborate? I tested it and it works fine for me. I mean you have to do it for each line of course.

Comment: @Andreas Try it with the input `'$ABCD:CABBAGE'`

Comment: @KonradRudolph ohhhhhh, you are right I really wasn't aware of that, so it uses every element in an iterable instead of the iterable itself. Ty for letting me know!

Comment: @usr2564301 The question was edited with the necessary detail; consider reopening it.

Comment: @KonradRudolph https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/27100998

Comment: @KonradRudolph No, the reopen review I linked is still ongoing and should be reviewable.

Comment: @SamuelLiew Oh, I misread “reviewable” as “viewable”. Anyway, yes, I’m aware. But since items sometimes tend to languish for a very long time in that queue I thought I’d nudge the original close voters here, since their concerns were presumably addressed by the edit, and since the system unfortunately doesn’t currently automate these notifications.

Comment: @Elena_w Until this question is (hopefully, at some point) reopened again, try out `df['Text'] = df['Text'].str.replace(r'\$ABCD: ', '')`, and read the documentation at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html

Answer (score 1):

```
db= #assuming your data in string type

db=db.split('\n')

result=''

for x in db:
    result+=x[6:]+'\n'
```